# What is a good resource for database design on Bigtable/S3/Azure style databases?

Tags: amazon-s3, nosql, bigtable, azure-table-storage

Coming from a relational database background, I can make the transition to document oriented databases pretty quickly. Many of the most valuable "relations" are maintained by the hierarchy of the document. Many of the DODB variants of NoSQL also offer a very rich query language as well. This subset of NoSQL I think I understand.

I am looking for a good reference for designing around the database style implemented by Azure Table Storage, S3, and BigTable. It seems like all of the samples I see are trivial implementations.

Do you know of any non-trivial treatments of design in this space?

Comment: Amazon S3 is just a file storage system. You must mean SimpleDB? - http://aws.amazon.com/simpledb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Azure Tables specifically (Microsoft's NoSQL database) the following blog post provides some good insight and talks to a couple of patterns to consider http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/11/06/windows-azure-storage-client-library-2-0-tables-deep-dive.aspx

Comment: Wow. I had forgotten about this question being posted. There are a lot a great patterns in that paper.

Answer (score 0):

Oren Eini (alias [Ayende Rahien](http://www.ayende.com/about-me.aspx)) has written a number of [blog posts](http://ayende.com/Blog/category/565.aspx) about designing NoSql databases for RavenDB - his own NoSql implementation.

I guess some of it is specific to RavenDB, but lots would also apply to other NoSql databases.